# String Similarity using fuzzywuzzy on big data

Tags: python, performance, strings, csv, edit-distance

I have a file in which I was to check the string similarity within the names in a particular column. I use fuzzywuzzy token sort ratio algorithm as it is required for my use case. here is the code, is there a way to speed it up? It is taking a lot of time for 30000 records.

```
import csv
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

data = pd.read_csv('D:\\Sim_Input.csv')

Dishes = data['Product_Name']

threshold_ratio = 85

with open('D:\\Sim_Score.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n', )
    writer.writerow(['tag4'])
    for str_1, str_2 in itertools.permutations(Dishes, 2):
        list = []
        ratio = (fuzz.token_sort_ratio(str_1, str_2))
        if ratio > threshold_ratio:
            row = (str_1, str_2, ratio)
            list.append(row)
            print(list)
            writer.writerow(list)
```

I need the output in a csv file with the names of ItemA, ItemB and similarity score, where the similarity should be above 85.

Comment: Makes sense... You're computing fuzzy similarity across 899,970,000 different permutations. Any reason you can't use combinations instead? `itertools.combinations(Dishes, 2)` should give you only 449,985,000 combinations, but you'd still consider every pair of dishes.

Comment: Are you/can you run this on a multi-core machine? This code would be easy to parallelize

Comment: I have a 8 core machine, Intel I7. How can this be parallelize?

Comment: can I use generators to make this run fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid processing each dish so many times, you can use this to process them only 1 time:

```
dishes = ["pizza with bacon", "pizza with extra cheese", "vegetarian pizza", "cheese and bacon pizza", "bacon with pizza"]

processedDishes = []

for dish in dishes:
    processedDishes.append(fuzz._process_and_sort(dish, True, True))

for dish1, dish2 in itertools.combinations(enumerate(processedDishes), 2):  
    if fuzz.ratio(dish1[1], dish2[1]) >= 85:
        print(dishes[dish1[0]], dishes[dish2[0]])
```

You can then combine this with @scnerd solution to add multiprocessing

If you know your data is all the same type, you can further optimize it:

```
dishes = ["pizza with bacon", "pizza with extra cheese", "vegetarian pizza", "cheese and bacon pizza", "bacon with pizza"]

processedDishes = []
matchers = []

for dish in dishes:
    if dish:
        processedDish = fuzz._process_and_sort(dish, True, True)
        processedDishes.append(processedDish)
        matchers.append(fuzz.SequenceMatcher(None, processedDish))


for dish1, dish2 in itertools.combinations(enumerate(processedDishes), 2):
    matcher = matchers[dish1[0]]
    matcher.set_seq2(dish2[1])
    ratio = int(round(100 * matcher.ratio()))

    if ratio >= 85:
        print(dishes[dish1[0]], dishes[dish2[0]])
```

**Update:** checked how these ratios are calculated, here is a more efficient answer that avoids a lot of checks between pairs:

```
dishes = ["pizza with bacon", "pizza with extra cheese", "vegetarian pizza", "cheese and bacon pizza", "bacon with pizza", "a"]


processedDishes = []
matchers = []

for dish in dishes:
    if dish:
        processedDish = fuzz._process_and_sort(dish, True, True)
        processedDishes.append({"processed": processedDish, "dish": dish})


processedDishes.sort(key= lambda x: len(x["processed"]))

for idx, dish in enumerate(processedDishes):
    length = len(dish["processed"])
    matcher = fuzz.SequenceMatcher(None, dish["processed"])
    for idx2 in range(idx + 1, len(processedDishes)):
        dish2 = processedDishes[idx2]
        if 2 * length / (length + len(dish2["processed"])) < 0.85: # upper bound
            break

        matcher.set_seq2(dish2["processed"])

        if matcher.quick_ratio() >= 0.85 and matcher.ratio() >= 0.85: # should also try without quick_ratio() check
            print(dish["dish"], dish2["dish"])
```

Comment: This is great! I used your code and combine with @scnerd Multiprocessing and the entine 30000 ran in 15 minutes with permutations. It used to take some 8 hours. Even with the code that scnerd with, it took 5 hours.

Comment: @RishabOberoi impressive :). Maybe you should post final code combining both as an answer too

Comment: @RishabOberoi check my update

Comment: Yes, the algo works exactly how you implemented in the updated code. This is again very fast. let me work on my code and will share the complete solution that I am building.

Answer (score 8):

The first algorithmic recommendation is to use `itertools.combinations` instead of `.permutations`, since you don't care about order. This assumes `fuzz.token_sort_ratio(str_1, str_2) == fuzz.token_sort_ratio(str_2, str_1)`. There are half as many combinations as there are permutations, so that gives you a free 2x speedup.

This code also lends itself easily to parallelization. On an i7 (8 virtual cores, 4 physical), you could probably expect this to give you ~4-8x speedup, but that depends on a lot of factors. The least intrusive way to do this is to use [`multiprocessing.Pool.map` or `.imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def ratio(strings):
    s1, s2 = strings
    return s1, s2, fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1, s2)

with open('D:\\Sim_Score.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n', )
    writer.writerow(['tag4'])

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for s1, s2, r in pool.imap_unordered(ratio, itertools.combinations(Dishes, 2)):
            if r > threshold_ratio:
                writer.writerow([(s1, s2, r)])
```

All told, I'd expect these changes to give you 5-10x speedup, depending heavily on the number of cores you have available.

For reference, a generator comprehension version of this might look something like:

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    writer.writerows((s1, s2, r)
                     for s1, s2, r in pool.imap_unordered(ratio, itertools.combinations(Dishes, 2))
                     if r > threshold_ratio)
```

That version has a some, but very little, performance improvement over the non-comprehension version, and IMO is harder to read/maintain.

One other minor thing I noticed in testing my code was that `fuzzywuzzy` recommends installing `python-Levenshtein` in order to run faster; when I did so, it ran about 20x slower than when it used the built-in `SequenceMatcher`. When I uninstalled `python-Levenshtein` it got fast again. That seems very odd to me, but it's certainly something worth trying.

Finally, if performance is important, you could consider digging into what `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` does to see if you could remove some repeated work. For example, it's tokenizing and sorting each string again every time you pass it in, so maybe you could pre-tokenize/sort the strings and only run the ratio logic inside the main loop. A quick dig tells me that `token_sort_ratio` is two main steps:

1. Preprocess each string using `fuzz._process_and_sort`
2. Run `fuzz.partial_ratio` against the processed strings

I'm not able to get this to run faster at the moment, but I'll edit and update this answer if I can get that approach to work well.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this and will post the result. Please share and update when you find something.

Comment: Hi, I tried your updated code of 200000 approx distinct records. The previous code took 3 hours and the updated one took 47 minutes.